# Gnome Boxes was denied permission to access $HOME/.local where my old VM file is located, what should I do?

Tags: gnome, permissions, virtualization

Recently I upgraded from Ubuntu 21.10 to 22.04.  I did not carry over any apps, but I did keep a separate /home partition, which contained a Windows 10 virtual machine file which was created with Gnome Boxes.

I just downloaded Gnome Boxes 42.0.1, and I want to boot my VM.  Gnome Boxes stored the VM in $HOME/.local/share/gnome-boxes/images.  When I try to navigate to this folder in Gnome Boxes, I get a "permission denied" popup when clicking on $HOME/.local.

I did not change any file permissions.  Either the OS upgrade did it, or Gnome Boxes now wants some new permissions that it did not need before.

Advice is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: did you install Gnome boxes as a snap or a .deb?

Comment: Hi @Esther, I installed the Snap.

Comment: snap applications are sandboxed and can't access everything in the system, so that is probably the issue. not sure how to fix, but that at least will give you a way to start looking

Comment: @Esther Thanks again for your reply.  Interesting, because I'm almost certain that I installed Boxes from Snap on Ubuntu 21.10, and, I created the VM in $HOME/.local/share/gnome-boxes/images using that install.  Boxes must have had read-write privileges to that folder in the past.  Now it doesn't?  Odd.  Maybe I'll uninstall the Snap and grab the DEB version instead.

Comment: @Esther I got a non-Snap version of Gnome Boxes using Synaptic Package Manager instead of Ubuntu Software Center.  I got version 42.2-stable.  So two things have changed.  Boxes now has permission to access $HOME/.local, great!  Unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I got a hint from @Esther which solved the problem.

I uninstalled the Gnome Boxes Snap version 42.0.1 which Ubuntu Software Center supplied.  I switched over to Synaptic Package Manager and used it to install a non-Snap version of Gnome Boxes: I got version 42.2-stable.  So two things have changed.

Boxes now has permission to access $HOME/.local, great!

Unfortunately, my VM still will not boot.  I get a "Failed to start" error message, and a button which opens a troubleshooting log.  Based on the timestamps, the log documents several successful VM starts from February through June -- but, nothing from today's failed boot attempt.

That's a different problem, so I'm marking this question as answered and moving on.